# cld Tukey letters are not showing the right groups when compared with means

Tags: r, statsmodels, tukey

I'm running Tukey HSD post hoc tests using the `multcomp` package and its `cld` function to analyse the differences in my linear mixed-effect model in a nested split-plot designed trial. For some reason the Tukey letters are not showing the right groups anymore (it used to work): the means show clearly a different picture to what I would assign the letter display to. Can someone tell me what is wrong here?

Means and standard errors

```
#SE function
sem = function(x)
      {
           n = sum(!is.na(x))
           sqrt(var(x,na.rm=T)/n)
      }

mean<-tapply(mydata$p5, list(mydata$ft), mean, na.rm=TRUE)#means
se<-tapply(mydata$p5, list(mydata$ft), sem)#se
cbind(mean, se)
```

My model with the Tukey letters:

```
mydata.lme<-lme(p5~ft, data=mydata, random=~1|bl/yr/cp/vr/amf,na.action=na.omit)
tuk=summary(glht(mydata.lme,linfct=mcp(ft="Tukey")),test=univariate())#glht
cld(tuk,level=0.05, decreasing = TRUE) #letters
summary(tuk)
```

And my wicked dataset (sorry for that):

```
> dput(mydata)
structure(list(yr = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
    qn = c(29.2, 29.2, 29.1, 29.1, 26.2, 26.2, 26.1, 26.1, 26.1, 
    26.1, 26.2, 26.2, 29.1, 29.1, 29.2, 29.2, 26.1, 26.1, 26.2, 
    26.2, 29.1, 29.1, 29.2, 29.2, 29.2, 29.2, 29.1, 29.1, 26.2, 
    26.2, 26.1, 26.1, 20.2, 20.2, 20.1, 20.1, 19.2, 19.2, 19.1, 
    19.1, 19.1, 19.1, 19.2, 19.2, 20.1, 20.1, 20.2, 20.2, 19.1, 
    19.1, 19.2, 19.2, 20.1, 20.1, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.1, 
    20.1, 19.2, 19.2, 19.1, 19.1, 4.2, 4.2, 4.1, 4.1, 3.2, 3.2, 
    3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.2, 3.2, 4.1, 4.1, 4.2, 4.2, 3.1, 3.1, 
    3.2, 3.2, 4.1, 4.1, 4.2, 4.2, 4.2, 4.2, 4.1, 4.1, 3.2, 3.2, 
    3.1, 3.1, 32.2, 32.2, 32.1, 32.1, 33.2, 33.2, 33.1, 33.1, 
    33.1, 33.1, 33.2, 33.2, 32.1, 32.1, 32.2, 32.2, 33.1, 33.1, 
    33.2, 33.2, 32.1, 32.1, 32.2, 32.2, 32.2, 32.2, 32.1, 32.1, 
    33.2, 33.2, 33.1, 33.1), bl = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), 
    pl = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
    13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
    33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 
    45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 
    65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 
    77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 
    89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 
    108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 
    118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 
    128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 145L, 
    146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 
    156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L), cp = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("CCP", "OCP"), class = "factor"), 
    vr = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("ASZ", 
    "SKY"), class = "factor"), amf = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("M0", "M1"), class = "factor"), 
    ft = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
    2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
    4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("BG", 
    "CM", "MN", "ZE"), class = "factor"), p5 = c(24.2, 3.5, 4.133333333, 
    NA, 44.23333333, 26.03333333, 21.16666667, 14.83333333, 7.866666667, 
    20.7, 13.5, 31.33333333, 17.7, 8.5, 20, 22.53333333, 25.43333333, 
    29.5, 24.33333333, 28.73333333, 21.33333333, 6.4, 12.33333333, 
    31.36666667, 47.53333333, 13, 0, 20.03333333, 26.66666667, 
    NA, 32.83333333, 32.2, 4.533333333, 15.53333333, 29.4, 11.7, 
    10.5, 12.4, 4.733333333, 28.53333333, 31.16666667, 10.06666667, 
    19.3, 14.73333333, 7.2, 12.2, 31.73333333, 6.666666667, 49, 
    26, 49.5, 29.36666667, 34, 42, 22, 23, 25.53333333, 56.73333333, 
    63.16666667, 30.2, 32.7, 36.53333333, 8.033333333, 23.4, 
    18.53333333, 30.5, 51.33333333, 30.2, 43.66666667, 1.166666667, 
    8.833333333, 49.53333333, 17.2, NA, 35.73333333, 37.86666667, 
    29.76666667, 55.86666667, 29.16666667, 48.83333333, 30.4, 
    34.2, 5.866666667, 34.2, 8.533333333, 16.33333333, 2.866666667, 
    31.33333333, 25.66666667, 25.33333333, 33, 2.333333333, 24.2, 
    1.333333333, 28.83333333, 40.33333333, 29.16666667, 39, 14.86666667, 
    40.86666667, 17.76666667, 34.23333333, 28.53333333, 35, 23.33333333, 
    30.66666667, 39.06666667, 27, 18.3, 18.06666667, 2.2, 24.53333333, 
    8.366666667, 27.86666667, 18.66666667, 4.666666667, 8, 3.666666667, 
    8.333333333, 20.5, 8.733333333, 22.16666667, 12.53333333, 
    4.333333333, 2.6, 16.03333333, 21.1, 9.866666667)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-128L))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Find more details [here](https://schmidtpaul.github.io/DSFAIR/compactletterdisplay.html).

```r
library(nlme)
library(emmeans)
library(multcomp)
library(multcompView)

# model
model <- lme(
  p5 ~ ft,
  data = mydata,
  random =  ~ 1 | bl / yr / cp / vr / amf,
  na.action = na.omit
)

model_means <- emmeans::emmeans(object = model,
                                pairwise ~ "ft",
                                adjust = "tukey")

# add letters to each mean
model_means_cld <- multcomp::cld(object = model_means$emmeans,
                                 Letters = letters, 
                                 alpha = 0.05)

# show output
model_means_cld
#>  ft emmean   SE df lower.CL upper.CL .group
#>  MN   14.0 2.56  3     5.84     22.1  a    
#>  BG   20.4 2.53  3    12.34     28.5  a    
#>  CM   28.0 2.56  3    19.88     36.2   b   
#>  ZE   30.1 2.56  3    21.96     38.2   b   
#> 
#> Degrees-of-freedom method: containment 
#> Confidence level used: 0.95 
#> P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 4 estimates 
#> significance level used: alpha = 0.05 
#> NOTE: Compact letter displays can be misleading
#>       because they show NON-findings rather than findings.
#>       Consider using 'pairs()', 'pwpp()', or 'pwpm()' instead.
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>